# How to replace a value in Java

Tags: java

So I am attempting to write a program where you enter your grades, totals them up, averages, and then drops the lowest grade. This is what I have so far, however, when I try to run the program I receive the average of 92 when I enter the values 100,100,75.

The average should be printing as 100. What is wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class l3_drop_lowest_slide36 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double grade;
        int count;
        double minGrade;
        double sumGrade;
        double average;

        System.out.println("Begin entering grades below. When done, type -1.");
        System.out.println();

        count = 0;
        sumGrade = 0;
        grade = 0;
        minGrade = 100;

        while ( grade != -1 ) {

            sumGrade += grade;
            count++;
            System.out.print("Grade: ");
            grade = input.nextDouble();

        } 

        if ( grade < minGrade ) {

            minGrade = grade;

        } 

        if ( grade == -1 ) {
            sumGrade = sumGrade - minGrade;
            count = count - 1;
            average = (sumGrade / count);
            System.out.print("Your average is: " +average);
        }



    } 


    }
```

Comment: Well, the average of 100, 100, and 75 *is* 92 (or, rather, 91.66666666666667) so it looks like your program is working correctly. :)

Comment: no it's not. if you read what he's trying to do, he is trying to drop lowest grade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    while ( grade != -1 ) {

        sumGrade += grade;
        count++;
        System.out.print("Grade: ");

        grade = input.nextDouble();

        if(grade < minGrade && grade != -1)
            minGrade = grade;

    } 

    sumGrade = sumGrade - minGrade;
    count = count - 1;
    average = (sumGrade / count);
    System.out.print("Your average is: " +average);
```

This way you are dropping out the minimum grade.

Comment: You can get rid of the if ( grade == -1), it must be -1 to get there

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if ( grade < minGrade ) {

            minGrade = grade;

        }
```

should be inside your

```
while ( grade != -1 ) {

            }
```

Because when you get -1, -1 < 100 and **minGrade = -1**.

> sumGrade - minGrade = (100+100+75) - (-1) = 276

And when u divide 276/3 = 92.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `grade = input.nextDouble();` first and then checking if it's -1. Your while loop runs 4 times and not 3. So, essentially your count is 4 and not 3. Your minimum grade is -1 (the last input value) and not 75. Fix that logic and you should be good.